# How to hide shipping zones for a certain category in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

Essentially I'm trying to hide some shipping zones for a certain category
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Example-
There are 5 shipping zones and When Pizza Category is choose 2 shipping zones must be hidden

Maybe Helpful- 
I used this code to Hide other shipping methods if the free shipping is enable on a certain category

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_in_zone', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_in_zone( $rates, $package ) {

// Only unset rates if free_shipping is available
if ( isset( $rates['advanced_free_shipping'] ) ) {
     unset( $rates['shipping_method_0_flat_rate2'] );
}     

return $rates;

}
```